# complete headers for PHP MAIL AND SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp

i need the complete or the most complete PHP header i could use for my mail, so that the probability that my mail would not go to spam...

Comment: I just [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332959/php-mail-junk-sometimes-not-even-received/4333003#4333003) and the reality is, its MUCH less likely to be your headers then it is your server/mail server set up. Although some of that server setup does affect the headers that get generated.

Comment: Headers are only part of any decent spam filter's scoring mechanism. The actual source server, the content of the mail, the presence of the usual trigger words (`p3n1s p1llz!!@!!`) and so on all add to the score.

Comment: the source server is decent, as well as the content, even the spf is turned on, but its still sent to spam... and people say to me its because of the headers.. please help

Answer (score 0):

Check that your headers **return-path** and **from** are real.

regards,
/t