# The PHP contact form is not working

Tags: php, html, email, web

I'm trying to send filled HTML form by PHP. Actually, it doesn't show any errors but email is not be sent.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "viva7real@yandex.ru"; //my Email
    $from = $_POST['email']; // sender's email
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any bugs or mistakes in the code?

Comment: What do your error logs say?

Comment: `mail()` is not a reliable function for sending emails. Better use a mailing library.

Comment: You can debug the result from the `mail()` function with `var_dump(mail(...))` and see if it returns true/false. For more verbose debugging try switching to https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: "*mail() is not a reliable function for sending emails.*" ... lol. Never had an issue with sending a few thousand `mail()` per day. "*Using PHPMailer, or swiftmailer or any other library won't increase your delivery rates in most cases: The most likely culprit is your server set up.*" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4333003/2960971). Also being blacklisted by the destination is a good chance.